# Replacement for spray.client.HttpConduit in spray 1.2.0

Tags: scala, spray

I'm trying to upgrade to scala 2.10 and use a newer version of spray. The class `spray.client.HttpConduit` no longer exists. There is no mention of replacement in the changelog of spray project, do you know what I should use instead? At the moment I am using it in a similar way to https://stackoverflow.com/a/17009061/557691. 
Thank you!

Comment: `HttpConduit` is gone for a while now in favor of `spray.client.pipelining.sendReceive`. See the documentation here: http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.0/spray-client/